# Creating figure (cycle) in latex

Tags: diagrams

I want to make a figure the same or similar to this one:

[image]

I really have no clue on how or where to start as I have very little `LaTeX` experience.

I would be very grateful if somebody could help.

Comment: Please upload a screenshot. The link above points to your local file.

Comment: I appologize. I edited my post. I hope the image is clear because I seem not able to import it in better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go colourful with `smartdiagram`:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=2.5cm,
arrow line width=0.2cm
}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
  \smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Insured \\ policy holder,Insurer \\ company}
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) {\usebox{\mybox}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (a.north) {Insurance policy covering risks};
    \node[anchor=north] at (a.south) {Fixed premium};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is something to get you started:

[image]

Steps:

1. Place the nodes:

   ```
   \node [align=left] (LEFT NODE)  at (0,0) {Left \\ Text};
   \node [align=left] (RIGHT NODE) at (7,0) {Right \\ Text};
   ```

   This creates two nodes named `(LEFT NODE)` and `(RIGHT NODE)`. I used absolute positioning, but for more complicated figures you should use relative positioning.
2. Each `\node` placed above provides several `anchor` points (see `TikZ/PGF` manual).  So, the bottom arrow and text is placed with.

   ```
   \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, double] 
       (LEFT NODE.south east) to[out=-80, in=-110] 
       node [pos=0.5, below, black] {Bottom Text}
       (RIGHT NODE.south west);
   ```

   where the arrow starts from `(LEFT NODE.south east)` (that is, the `south east` cornder of the `node` named `LEFT NODE`.  The `to` options define the `in` and `out` angles for the arrow.

   The text is placed `below` the arrow at `pos=0.5` (ie., midway). The arrow ends at the `south west` of the `node` named `RIGHT NODE.`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [align=left] (LEFT NODE)  at (0,0) {Left \\ Text};
    \node [align=left] (RIGHT NODE) at (7,0) {Right \\ Text};
    \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, double] 
            (LEFT NODE.south east) to[out=-80, in=-110] 
            node [pos=0.5, below, black] {Bottom Text}
            (RIGHT NODE.south west);
    \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, double] 
            (RIGHT NODE.north west) to[out=110, in=80] 
            node [pos=0.5, above, black] {Top Text}
            (LEFT NODE.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```